# Saving nested objescs in EF Core throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Considering I have the following JSON that I get from a service, what's the best way to insert it into a EF Core managed sqlite db?

The relationship would be:

Payment to PaymentType -> many-to-one

PaymentType to PayentUnit -> many-to-one

I don't need to back ref the parent, like having a list of Payment in the PaymentType POCO, or do I?

```
{
    "payments": [{
        "id": 1,
        "paymentType": {
            "id": 1,
            "paymentUnit": {
                "id": 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "paymentType": {
            "id": 2,
            "paymentUnit": {
                "id": 2
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "paymentType": {
            "id": 2,
            "paymentUnit": {
                "id": 2
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "paymentType": {
            "id": 4,
            "paymentUnit": {
                "id": 1
            }
        }
    }]
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PaymentUnit PaymentUnit { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentUnit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

On my OnModelCreating i have mapped the keys:
I mapped the Id's as keys on OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>()
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedNever();

modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>()
    .HasKey(p => p.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentType>()
    .Property(pt => pt.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedNever();

modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentType>()
    .HasKey(pt => pt.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentUnit>()
    .Property(pu => pu.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedNever();

modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentUnit>()
    .HasKey(pu => pu.Id);
```

But when I try to do a context.Payment.AddRamge(payments) i get an exception like https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3839. All on a clean DB. I've created the migrations and all.

Thank in advance!

Comment: What did you tried? And what is the problem with your attempt? SO is not for, `whats the best way?`, it is all about `why doesn't my solution work? (with example code)`

Comment: Just adited my question :)

Comment: I solved my problem, the answer is at https://github.com/rpedretti/EFCorePoc :)